# Is wrapping the function with the {} operator a valid replacement of 'UniformOutput', false in cellfun?

Tags: matlab, function, cell-array

I am using [`cellfun`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply a function to each cell in a cell array.

I know that I must set [`'UniformOutput'`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html#namevaluepairs) to `false` whenever the function returns non-scalar values, so that the outputs of the function are returned encapsulated in a cell array.

Take the following cell array as an example:

```
C1 = {[1 2 3], [4 5 6]};
```

`C1` has two cells and each cell contains a vector of three elements:

```
C1 =

  1×2 cell array

    [1×3 double]    [1×3 double]
```

If I want to add `1` to the contents in every cell, I can define the function `@(x) x + 1` and apply it using `cellfun` as follows:

```
C2 = cellfun(@(x) x + 1, C1, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

This works very well, but note that I need to make sure that `'UniformOutput'` is set to `false` as I explained before, otherwise an error would be thrown.

However, after reading [this thread](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/324431), I realized that if I wrap the function with the [cell array construction operator `{}`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html) like this `@(x) {x + 1}` then I don't need to set `'UniformOutput'` to `false`.

So the following command will generate the same results as in `C2` without throwing any errors:

```
C3 = cellfun(@(x) {x + 1}, C1);
```

In terms of code layout I prefer this approach since it is more compact and less verbose than the former, but I am not sure if this is always safe.

---

Thus my question is:

Can I always wrap the function with `{}` to avoid setting `'UniformOutput'` to `false`? Or are there any scenarios where such replacement would not work?

---

My research:

```
help cellfun
```

> `'UniformOutput'` -- a logical value indicating whether or not the
>   output(s) of `FUN` can be returned without encapsulation in a cell
>   array. If `true` (the default), `FUN` must return scalar values that
>   can be concatenated into an array.  If `true`, the outputs must be of
>   the following types:  numeric, logical, char, struct, cell.  If
>   `false`, `cellfun` returns a cell array (or multiple cell arrays),
>   where the (I,J,...)th cell contains the value FUN(C{I,J,...}, ...). 
>   When `'UniformOutput'` is `false`, the outputs can be of any type.

The following fragment is part of [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18240069/3599179) to a related question:

> [...] `cellfun` takes care of the dereference operation which is
>   required to do detailed operations on individual elements of a cell
>   when looping (that is, the `{}`) [...]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two scenarios I can think of where using [cell encapsulation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html) instead of the additional arguments [`...'UniformOutput', false)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html#namevaluepairs) would cause a problem, the first one being a much more likely scenario than the second:

- **Capturing multiple outputs:** Sometimes you may want to capture multiple outputs from the function you are applying, such as calling [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) on each element of your cell array and getting the additional index arguments. Using `...'UniformOutput', false)` we can easily do this:

  ```
  >> C1 = {[1 2 3], [4 5 6]};
  >> [C2, index] = cellfun(@(x) unique(x), C1, 'UniformOutput', false)
  C2 =
    1×2 cell array
      [1×3 double]    [1×3 double]
  index =
    1×2 cell array
      [3×1 double]    [3×1 double]
  ```

  However, this fails when using cell encapsulation:

  ```
  >> [C2, index] = cellfun(@(x) {unique(x)}, C1)
  Output argument "varargout{2}" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
  "@(x){unique(x)}".
  ```
- **Functions with no output:** I know what you're thinking: *"But if they produce no output, then I don't have to worry about collecting non-scalar values!"* True, but I'm imagining an admittedly unusual scenario where the function to be evaluated may be an additional parameter, like a function handle passed as an argument, so you don't know *a priori* how many outputs you'll be dealing with. Regardless, the two approaches differ for such a case:

  ```
  >> C1 = {[1 2 3], [4 5 6]};
  >> cellfun(@(x) disp(x), C1, 'UniformOutput', false);
       1     2     3
       4     5     6

  >> cellfun(@(x) {disp(x)}, C1);
  Error using disp
  Too many output arguments.
  Error in @(x){disp(x)}
  ```

  Probably not something you'll ever have to worry about, but I thought I'd include it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Wow..I didn't know that capturing multiple outputs with `cellfun` was even possible. This is an enlightening answer! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

From you question...

> Can I always wrap the function with {} to avoid setting 'UniformOutput' to false? Or are there any scenarios where such replacement would not work?

The short answer is **"NO"**. And I believe the major reason your anonymous function will fail is because it's lack of type checking and the programmer has little knowledge regarding the function returning type as well.

In fact, IMO you shouldn't struggled on either using cell indexing operator `{}` to wrap your return value or not in your anonymous function. A better practice will be to determine the return value type after calling `cellfun` or to check input value type before calling `cellfun`. Certainly, you can implement type checking procedure or `try...catch` in your [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html#buvtwop) as well to ensure the full control of your return type. And to be honest, knowing what you send and what you are going to receive is extremely important in Matlab.

In a nutshell, you shouldn't use `{}` to encapsulate your anonymous function unless you intentionally create a cell array as the return type, and you've known that the return value from the function you've called can be used to create a cell array.

FYI, if you have 2016b or later, while [function in script is possible](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html), you may create a function handle for `cellfun` within your script without creating a new file.